# Is it possible to query the relationship with the two tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, foreign-keys

I have two tables in my PostgreSQL database `enrollment`. Is it possible to query the  relationship with the two tables in PostgreSQL? Like for example:

```
Table1   Table2
column1  column2
```

In the illustration above, `column1` in `Table1` is connected to `columnn2` in `Table2`. A query example is very much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

The input of the query must be the two names of the table and the output must be the columns that make them connected.

Comment: Typically you would already know the relationship between the tables _before_ writing the query.  Can you look at the table structure and look for primary and foreign keys?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Im creating a dynamic database configuration where users are free to select tables that they would use. That's why Im looking for methods where I dont have to hard code the relationship between tables.

Comment: Check this data: `information_schema.referential_constraints`, `information_schema.constraint_table_usage`, `information_schema.constraint_column_usage`.

Comment: Just to understand what you are after... You want to select a column in a specific table and find out where this column is used as a FK? If that is what you want it is doable however it is not clear what do you expect if this chosen column is not the refrence origin. example:  userid in users is a PK, userid in logtable is FK to users, userid in logtable2 is FK to users. If in your case you choose userid in logtable. What would be the desired result? It is a "shared" column but it is not the SOURCE.

Comment: @java I edited my question above for more clarification :)